# Why My Java Spring MVC Servlet Filter Is Not Intercepting Incoming HttpRequest?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, servlet-filters

I'm debugging and existing Spring MVC project, I added a servlet filter [ ServletFilter ], which I intended to intercept all incoming httprequests, but how come only some requests are intercepted, most are not ? What should I do to intercept all incoming requests ?

My servlet filter looks like this :

```
import ...

public class ServletFilter implements Filter
{    
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException { }

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest,ServletResponse servletResponse,FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException,ServletException
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

My Java web app's web.xml looks like this :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

 <filter>
  <filter-name>Site_Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.builders.support.center.ServletFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Site_Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>supportCenter</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet>
  <description>Monitor servlet</description>
  <display-name>Monitor servlet</display-name>
  <servlet-name>Monitor</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.builders.support.center.Monitor</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>supportCenter</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
<!--  
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>supportCenter</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>supportCenter</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/newlogin</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 -->
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Monitor</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/servlet/Monitor</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <session-config>
  <session-timeout>360</session-timeout>
 </session-config>
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
 <error-page>
  <error-code>400</error-code>
  <location>/404error.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
 <error-page>
  <error-code>403</error-code>
  <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/exceptions/accessError.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
 <error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/404error.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
 <error-page>
  <error-code>408</error-code>
  <location>/404error.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
 <error-page>
  <error-code>500</error-code>
  <location>/404error.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
```

And my supportCenter-servlet.xml looks like this :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <!--
        - Application context definition for "SupportCenter" DispatcherServlet.
    -->

<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.builders.support.center.weblayer.springmvc.controllers"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>

    <bean id="supportCenterPropertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>/WEB-INF/properties/web-site.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView</value>
        </property>
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="urlMapping"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="/main.html">mainFormController</prop>

                <prop key="/login">mainFormController</prop>
                <prop key="/newlogin">mainFormController</prop>
                <prop key="/fail_login.html">failLoginViewController</prop>
                <prop key="/login.html">loginFormController</prop>
              ...

    <bean id="mainFormController"
          class="com.builders.support.center.weblayer.springmvc.controllers.MainFormController">
        <property name="sessionForm">
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
        <property name="commandName">
            <value>commandBean</value>
        </property>
        <property name="commandClass">
            <value>com.builders.support.center.weblayer.springmvc.command.beans.MainCommandBean</value>
        </property>
        <property name="formView">
            <value>main</value>
        </property>
        <property name="successView">
            <value>main.html</value>
        </property>
        <property name="bindOnNewForm">
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
   ...
```

Edit :

Here are the URLs, only the 3rd one works correctly, got intercepted, all others didn't get intercepted and showed a login screen.

[image]

Comment: What's the difference between the ones that do and the ones that don't get intercepted?

Comment: The ones got intercepted can be directed to certain links as I wanted to, the ones didn't get intercepted I can't control them, because I took over the project, they want me to quickly make some modifications to it and change some behavior ...

Comment: No, I mean: what URLs, are there other components involved, etc.? We need more details.

Comment: Some examples of intercepted and non-intercepted requests would be great

Comment: OK, I've included the urls, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks! Is the application deployed under the `/SupportCenter` root context?

Comment: With a filter mapping of `/*` all requests should be intercepted, independently of any other config. How are you sure they are not ? Did you put a log as first statement of `doFilter` ?

Comment: The application is deployed under the /SupportCenter.

Comment: I added "response.getWriter().println("Intercepted In ServletFilter");" in the filter as first line, and I can see it in the 3rd URL, which was intercepted, but all other 3 went straight to the login screen without showing this message.

Comment: I would prefere a `logger.error("Intercepted In ServletFilter")` or at least a `System.out.println("Intercepted In ServletFilter")` but something on server.

Comment: Do you have other filters in you configuration ?

Comment: @ Serge Ballesta : Thanks to your suggestion, after adding the System.out.println(), I found out the request was intercepted afterall, now I need to find out why it didn't work correctly after that.